# How to resolve "[Errno 2]" error while downloading files from s3 using awscli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have multiple text files in an s3 bucket and want to download them all. 
I have been working on bash linux terminal on windows. But I tried similar thing on windows terminal and it is showing the same error. In AWS Configuration, the output format is in text.

I have been using cp function with recursive but still cannot do that.

This is the code I used.

```
aws s3 cp s3://airport-data . --recursive
```

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR2y4.png)

Comment: It looks like it is trying to rename a temporary file into the "final" file, probably after the download completes. Not sure why it is happening. Does it work okay if you try to download a single, specific file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, it says the file does not exists.

Comment: I wonder if it is something strange with the bash terminal. Can you try running the same command in a PowerShell window?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Already did on on windows terminal. Same error

Comment: As a test, I would recommend creating a new bucket and copying from your local computer to the bucket using `aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://new-bucket/`. If that works, try copying it back with `aws s3 cp s3://new-bucket/foo.txt .` If that works, try replicating your recursive copy (be sure to include the slash after a bucket name/directory name). This should help you try to narrow-down the cause of your issue.